# Mobile client login to Spring REST server

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-security, mobile-application

I'm developing some mobile app using react-native, and server for it.

I need to make a secure login to a server from an app. For the server, I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Security.

I know that for site's Spring use form Login, and there are nothing difficult in configuring it, but when it comes to login from mobile app, i can't get any information about it.

If you know ways to do this, I will be very grateful for any info on this issue.

Comment: You can configure spring security for RESTful JSON API for login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you mention about is stateful authentication.

You have to take a look **[token based / stateless authentication](https://auth0.com/blog/stateless-auth-for-stateful-minds/)**.

There are many tutorials about **implementing JWT Authentication on Spring**. You can google about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot) I didn`t know that it calls JWT) 
You saved me ;)